# Hosting a TCP socket service in ASP.NET 5

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, tcplistener

I like ASP.NET Web API infrastructure for providing web based user interface.

I would like to host a true TCP/IP service that has nothing to do with HTTP protocol and it is not likely to benefit from middleware.

How do I do that?  Do I create this service as a singleton and add it in ConfigureServices with services.AddSingleton(..?)?

Details:  non-HTTP data upload protocol with SQLite database store, so there is no real DB in here.  Access data through REST api exposed by ASP.NET 5.

Thank you

Comment: If it is a true TCP service why couldn't you host it separately?

Comment: Reasons:

1. Deployment simplicity.
2. REST API is a way to access state of the service and not the other way around.